# Update snapshot.data before executing Cloud function

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This code creates an event by a user. Afterwards a cloud function grabs all "relevant_ users" and creates the same event for them as well. However, I want to change the field "timestamp" before it is created for all "relevant_users".

This way:

1. The user which creates the event has the current timestamp, "year 2022, 16 Juli"
2. The rest of users get a modified timestamp "year 2000, 16 Juli"

```
func createEvent() {
        Firestore.firestore().collection("event").document(self.eventId).setData([
                
            "author": [
                "uid": userProfile.uid,
                "username": userProfile.username,
                "photoURL": userProfile.photoURL.absoluteString
            ],
            "timestamp": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                
        ]) { (err) in
            if let err = err {
            }
        }
    }
```

```
exports.onCreateEvent = functions.firestore
    .document('event/{eventId}')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

      const eventData = snapshot.data();
      const eventId = context.params.eventId;
  
      const allusers = admin.firestore().collection("relevant_users");
      const querySnapshot = await allusers.get();

      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const userId = doc.id;
        admin.firestore().collection("userId").doc(eventId).set(eventData);
      });

    } 
}
```

Somehow i would need to grab the timestamp and update it before executing the rest of the cloud function.

```
const timestamp = snapshot.data().timestamp
```

Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is the timestamp in the cloud function supposed to be calculated if it's not the current timestamp?

Comment: My intent is to change the timestamp field for all "relevant_users" except for the user that created the event. This way i can easily filter content by date. In swift i can for example create an imaginary past date. let pastDate = dateFormatter.date("1 Jan 2000")!

Comment: The most surefire way is to unpack the document in the cloud function and create the new document with those fields (individually) with a pre-modified timestamp.

Comment: That would be very useful. Do you perhaps have any example or link on how this could be done ?

Comment: Is the cloud function written in JS?

Comment: The event is created in swift which then triggers the cloud function which is in JS.

Comment: Refer to the following link to get the document and its properties and then update them. Refer to the Node.JS examples as they are written using the same language and syntax usable in your cloud function. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#node.js_1